# CSS login function how to stay still on page

Tags: javascript, html

How can I stay on page until the user puts something on username box and password? and when the user puts something it should go to my next page.

```
function validateForm() {

var temp = document.getElementById("name").value;

if(temp=="")
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "username is required";

  temp = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (temp=="")
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "password is required";

  var user = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

Comment: You need to do something like showing in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981662/713789

Comment: You can put some setInterval kind of thing and check these both values

Answer (score 0):

Basically this depends on what you want to do with the form data. 
If there is an api call which you have to make with the form data you can send these values over an ajax call.After you have got the response to the api call you redirect to the different page using window.location.href

Also you can call this function on the form submit and check for the values. If there is another kind of processing involved other than the api call, do that and then redirect to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function validateForm() {

var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

if(name==""){
  document.getElementById("nameError").innerHTML = "username is required";
  }else{
  document.getElementById("nameError").innerHTML ="";
  }

var  pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (pass==""){
  document.getElementById("passwordError").innerHTML = "password is required";
  }else
  {
  document.getElementById("passwordError").innerHTML ="";
  }
  if(name !="" && pass !=""){
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  }

  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
<span id="nameError"></span>
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="password">
<span id="passwordError"></span>
<br/>
<button onClick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You don't need the else blocks since you are doing nothing with the innerHTML. Just leave if blocks and execute nothing if else happens.